# Which of the 4 ways to call super() in Python 3 to use?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, super

I wonder when to use what flavour of Python 3 [super](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super)().

```
Help on class super in module builtins:

class super(object)
 |  super() -> same as super(__class__, <first argument>)
 |  super(type) -> unbound super object
 |  super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
 |  super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)
```

Until now I've used `super()` only without arguments and it worked as expected (by a Java developer).

**Questions:**

- What does "bound" mean in this context?
- What is the difference between bound and unbound super object?
- When to use `super(type, obj)` and when `super(type, type2)`?
- Would it be better to name the super class like in `Mother.__init__(...)`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's use the following classes for demonstration:

```
class A(object):
    def m(self):
        print('m')

class B(A): pass
```

Unbound `super` object doesn't dispatch attribute access to class, you have to use descriptor protocol:

```
>>> super(B).m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'm'
>>> super(B).__get__(B(), B)
<super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>
```

`super` object bound to instance gives bound methods:

```
>>> super(B, B()).m
<bound method B.m of <__main__.B object at 0xb765dacc>>
>>> super(B, B()).m()
m
```

`super` object bound to class gives function (unbound methods in terms of Python 2):

```
>>> super(B, B).m
<function m at 0xb761482c>
>>> super(B, B).m()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: m() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)
>>> super(B, B).m(B())
m
```

See Michele Simionato's "Things to Know About Python Super" blog posts series ([1](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275), [2](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278), [3](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=237121)) for more information

Comment: The question is specifically about Python3, but Simionato's blog posts series are about Python2, and mention that *The advantage is that you avoid to repeat the name of the class in the calling syntax, since that name is hidden in the mangling mechanism of private names.*.  This is no longer true in Python3, so at least that one advantage is dated.

Comment: This answers the OP's "what does each do?" but it doesn't answer "when would you use each one?" Also it doesn't actually explain "unbound" vs "bound"; if `B` is a class name and `b = B()` is an instance, then `B` is an unbound object and `b` is a bound object.

Answer (score 9):

A quick note, the new usage of `super` is outlined in [PEP3135 New Super](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) which was implemented in python 3.0. Of particular relevance;

```
super().foo(1, 2)
```

to replace the old:

```
super(Foo, self).foo(1, 2)
```