# [python]: confused by super()

Tags: python, super

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Python super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super)

Class `B` subclasses class `A`, so in B's `__init__` we should call A's `__init__` like this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
```

But with `super()`, I saw something like this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()  #or super().__init__()
```

My questions are:

1. Why not `super(B, self).__init__(self)`? Just because the return proxy object is a bound one?
2. If I omit the second argument in super and the return proxy object is an unbound one, then should I write `super(B).__init__(self)`?

Comment: And many, many others -- please search first. [how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing) [how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) [usage-of-python-3-super](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771904/usage-of-python-3-super)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super()` returns an instance of the base class, so `self` gets implicitly passed to `__init__()` like in any other method call.

With regards to your second question, that's correct. Calling `super()` without an instance as the second argument returns a reference to the class itself, not an instance constructed from your subclass instance.