# Doesn't Python's super() built-in violate DRY?

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is obviously a reason for this but I am not experienced enough to recognise it.

This is the example given in the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg) # Why do we have to mention 'C' again?
```

Is there not a way of 'knowing' the type from within the instance method that doesn't rely on duplicating the name of the class 'C'? Seems like the example could lead to a situation where the class name is updated but the type parameter in the super function call becomes stale?

Comment: That may be one reason for allowing `super().method(arg)` in Py3.

Comment: I think in py3 this is no longer the case

Comment: In Python 3 you can just say `super()`.  It requires compile-time analysis that simply doesn't exist in Python 2.

Comment: You don't have to do this in Python 3 (where the type system has been overhauled), so I suspect it's an artifact of how classes were wedged into Python 2.

Comment: @martineau, it doesn't matter whether `C` has multiple bases.  Note that *none* of the bases are passed to `super()`.

Comment: This is fixed in python 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10482953/2647279 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771904/usage-of-python-3-super

Comment: I love Python. This is one of the only mildly unintuitive things I've ever encountered in the language.. and it's fixed already ;-)

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, DRY is more about large sections of code being duplicated; on the other hand, yes, the class name in `super()` calls can become stale (it's happened to me).

In Python 3, `super()` has been revamped to not require the class name, so long as the function is defined inside the class -- so not a problem unless you are monkey-patching.

Answer (score 1):

The same way self is called manually in python super is a simple function, I mean, python functions doesn't know the execution context. This behaviour is practical for monkey patching for example.

For example, I took your C class from pypi and you update it every month as it's a useful class. I want to modify it's method behaviour so it'll update the comportment of other of my requirements using your C class:

```
from utils import do_magic
from a import C

def method(self, arg):
    super(C, self).method(arg)
    do_magic(self)

C.method = method
```