# Python "private" classmethod and DRY

Tags: python, dry, class-method

Occasionally, a class will have a ["private"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python) `@classmethod` which other methods call:

```
class FooClassThisSometimesHasALongNameEspIfAUnittestSubclasss(...):
    @classmethod
    def foo():
        ... 

    def bar(self):
        ...
        FooClassThisSometimesHasALongNameEspIfAUnittestSubclasss.foo()
        ...
```

As can be seen, the class name is repeated; it's admittedly probably not serious enough to cause a meltdown of current technology followed by a zombie apocalypse, but it's still a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) violation, and somewhat annoying.

The answer to a [similar question  about `super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599817/doesnt-pythons-super-built-in-violate-dry) stated that this is [one of the reasons for the Py3's new `super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic).

In the absence of some magic `normal()` function (which, as opposed to `super()`, returns the current class), is there some way to avoid the repetition?

Comment: Is there a reason not to do `def bar(self): self.foo(); ...`? You can still call a class method with `self`, but now I'm wondering if this is against some kind of convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
self.__class__.foo()
```

Comment: That's very useful, thanks! However, it being so simple, why wasn't this used for ``super``?

Comment: @AmiTavory: super() can call parent classes but also sibling classes. It's therefore a different concept from using `self.__class__`.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is a bit different and concerns the delta between the old ``super`` and the new one. Your excellent answer implies that DRY should not have really been a consideration, and yet is somehow was.

Comment: @AmiTavory: the changes to super() in Python 3.x were indeed made to avoid repeating yourself. I'm not sure how my answer implies DRY should not be a consideration? In principle you could also have written super(self.__class__, self) in Python 2.x but most usage out there tends to repeat the class name. In any case this was a bad thing and that's why changes were made to super().

Comment: or `type(self).foo` if you don't care for all the double-underscoring.

Comment: Actually, since this is a `classmethod`, you can call it on an instance without any trouble as `self.foo`.