# What is the difference between super() with arguments and without arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pygame, super

I encountered a code which uses the `super()` method in 2 different ways, and I can't understand what's the difference in the logic.

I'm learning right now the `pygame` module and I got a task to create a class of a `Ball` which inherits from `Sprite` which is a class from the `pygame` module (if I'm not mistaken).

I encountered this code:

```
import pygame

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()
```

And I can't understand the difference from:

```py
import pygame

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
```

(Argument of `super()` method)

What is the difference between those code blocks in their logic? Why do I need to pass to `super()` method arguments? What are those arguments required to be?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Python-3.x you generally don't need the arguments for `super` anymore. That's because they are inserted magically (see [PEP 3135 -- New Super](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/)).

The two argument call and the no-argument call are identical *if*:

- The first argument is the class in which the method is defined that uses `super`. In your case it's `Ball` so the condition is satisfied.
- and the second argument to `super` is the *first* argument of the method. In your case that's `self` which is the first argument of the method so that condition is also satisfied.

So in your case there's **no difference** between the two examples!

---

However there are some rare cases in which you actually need to call `super` with different arguments (either with 1 or 2 argument/-s). The documentation of super is a good starting point:

```
>>> help(super)
Help on class super in module builtins:

class super(object)
 |  super() -> same as super(__class__, <first argument>)
 |  super(type) -> unbound super object
 |  super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
 |  super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)
 |  Typical use to call a cooperative superclass method:
```

But I assume your question was mostly about the difference in your example (where there is no difference) and these `super` calls that require arguments are **very rare** and quite an advanced topic, so I'll leave them out of this answer.

However there are some resources that might help if you're interested in the differences:

- [Which of the 4 ways to call super() in Python 3 to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2771904/5393381)
- [How can I use super() with one argument in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30190185/5393381)