# Python file organization for chainable functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, dependencies

I'm writing a Python3.x framework that has *generators* and *filters*.  I have a compact syntax for chaining the output of generators and filters into filters, but file organization feels inelegant.  Here's what I mean.

Assume Renderer is the super class for both generators and filters:

```
# file: renderer.py -- defines the common superclass used by generators and filters
class Renderer(object):
    def render():
      # Every subclass provides a `render` function that emits some data...
      pass
```

```
# file: gen1.py -- defines a generator
class Gen1(Renderer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gen1, self).__init__()

    def render(self):
        ... emit some data
```

```
# file: filt1.py -- defines a filter that takes any Renderer object as an input
class Filt1(Renderer):
    def __init__(self, input, param):
        super(Filt1, self).__init__()
        self._input = input
        self._param = param

    def render():
        ... call self._input.render() to fetch and act on data before emitting it
```

```
# file: filt2.py -- defines a filter that takes any Renderer object as an input
class Filt2(Renderer):
    def __init__(self, input):
        super(Filt2, self).__init__()
        self._input = input

    def render():
        ... call self._input.render() to fetch and act on data before emitting it
```

```
# file: render_module.py -- a module file to bring in all the components
from renderer.py import Renderer
from gen1.py import Gen1
from filt1.py import Filt1
from filt2.py import Filt2
```

#### What I'd like

What I'd like is for a user of the platform to be able to write code like this, which chains the output of `gen1` into `filt1`, and the output of `filt1` into `filt2`:

```
import render_module as rm

chain = rm.Gen1().filt1(123).filt2()
chain.render()
```

#### What I've done

What I've done is add the following to renderer.py.  This works, but see "The Problem to Solve" below.

```
class Renderer(object):
    def render():
      # emit some data...
      pass

    def filt1(self, param):
        return rm.Filt1(self, parm)

    def filt2(self):
        return rm.Filt1(self)

import render_module as rm  # at end of file to avoid a circular dependency
```

#### The Problem to Solve

It feels wrong to pollute the common superclass with specific mentions of each subclass.  The clear indication of code smell is the `import` statement at the end of `renerer.py`.

But I haven't figured out a better way to refactor and organize the files.  What's the pythonic approach out of this conundrum?

Comment: Is this intended to run as Python 2? If so, you should probably tag it as such.

Comment: @Brian Done.  It's strictly Python3.  (I thought Python3 was the default by now...)

Comment: In that case, it's worth noting that inheriting from `object` and invoking super with arguments  are only needed for compatibility with Python 2. If you're only writing for Python 3, you can just write `class Foo:` and `super().method()`. See also [Why do Python classes inherit object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/11082165) and [What is the difference between super() with arguments and without arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57945407/11082165)

Comment: @Brian Thanks - that will neaten up my __init__() functions, but -- if I understand correctly -- doesn't address the file org question.  Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, that was a side note.

Comment: Also, if you haven't considered it already, this sort of high-level design question might get better attention over on [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Brian [Software Engineering SE] -- good suggestion.  To avoid redundancy, I'll let it simmer here for a while before cross-posting.  Thanks.