# Python, Pandas, subclass: Why is __init__ running repeatedly when print is called or when subclassing the subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subclass

I understood that `__init__` method would only be called when an object is instantiated. However, some tests with Pandas DataFrames have produced some curious and surprising results that are stopping me from achieving what I wanted to achieve. Any help in understanding what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

The below:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series


class ASeries(Series):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return ASeries

    @property
    def _constructor_expanddim(self):
        return AFrame


class AFrame(DataFrame):
    a_count = 0
    thing = 'a'

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return AFrame

    @property
    def _constructor_sliced(self):
        return ASeries

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AFrame, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__class__.a_count += 1
        print('a', self.__class__.a_count)


class BSeries(Series):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return BSeries

    @property
    def _constructor_expanddim(self):
        return BFrame


class BFrame(AFrame):
    b_count = 0
    thing = 'b'

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return BFrame

    @property
    def _constructor_sliced(self):
        return BSeries

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BFrame, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__class__.b_count += 1
        print('b', self.__class__.b_count)
```

```
b = BFrame(
    [
        {
            'a': 'a',
            'b': 'Something',
            'c': 1,
            'd': 'aa',
            'e': 'Somethings',
        },
        {
            'a': 'a',
            'b': 'Something else',
            'c': 1,
            'd': 'aa',
            'e': 'Somethings',
        },
    ],
)
print(b, type(b))
```

Gives this output, showing that, as I expected, each `__init__` method is only being run once:

```
a 1
b 1
   a               b  c   d           e
0  a       Something  1  aa  Somethings
1  a  Something else  1  aa  Somethings <class '__main__.BFrame'>
```

Process finished with exit code 0

However, if I then make some of the column names longer:

```
b = BFrame(
    [
        {
            'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': 'a',
            'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 'Something',
            'cccccccccccccccc': 1,
            'dddddddddddddddd': 'aa',
            'e': 'Somethings',
        },
        {
            'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': 'a',
            'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 'Something else',
            'cccccccccccccccc': 1,
            'dddddddddddddddd': 'aa',
            'e': 'Somethings',
        },
    ],
)
print(b, type(b))
```

I get the below, showing that the the first subclass is running, apparently, recursively:

```
a 1
b 1
a 1
a 2
a 3
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  ...  dddddddddddddddd           e
0                a        Something  ...                aa  Somethings
1                a   Something else  ...                aa  Somethings

[2 rows x 5 columns] <class '__main__.BFrame'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I remove the print call though:

```
a 1
b 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I then use the same data on the first subclass, which directly subclasses the DataFrame, the `__init__` method seems to now run four times, but it's the same data as above:

```
a = AFrame(
    [
        {
            'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': 'a',
            'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 'Something',
            'cccccccccccccccc': 1,
            'dddddddddddddddd': 'aa',
            'e': 'Somethings',
        },
        {
            'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': 'a',
            'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 'Something else',
            'cccccccccccccccc': 1,
            'dddddddddddddddd': 'aa',
            'e': 'Somethings',
        },
    ],
)
print(a, type(a))
```

Giving:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  ...  dddddddddddddddd           e
0                a        Something  ...                aa  Somethings
1                a   Something else  ...                aa  Somethings

[2 rows x 5 columns] <class '__main__.AFrame'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, if I remove the print call, I get:

```
a 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is anyone able to diagnose and explain what is happening here and how I can avoid this as extensions of this working are impossible to run currently but I'm hoping that understanding and fixing this behaviour will be the solution.

Comment: Is `_constructor_sliced` being called where it was not before?

Comment: FYI, you can just write `super()` instead of `super(BFrame, self)`. The latter syntax was only needed in Python 2.x. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945407/what-is-the-difference-between-super-with-arguments-and-without-arguments

Comment: I suspect the `__str__()` method of `Series` and/or `DataFrame` makes temporary copies in some cases.